# Error encountered implementing OAuth 2.0 Resource Server multi-tenancy

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented code as specified [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#resolving-the-tenant-by-claim) to add the multi-tenancy by issuer feature to my Spring Security configuration. However, when my Spring Boot application starts, I encounter the following error:

```
2021-10-26 | 10:31:37.762 | main | WARN | ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext | Trace: | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
2021-10-26 | 10:31:39.361 | main | ERROR | o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter | Trace: |
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your configuration.
```

The documentation states:

> This is nice because the issuer endpoints are loaded lazily. In fact, the corresponding JwtAuthenticationProvider is instantiated only when the first request with the corresponding issuer is sent.

I wouldn't think that at application startup a `JwtDecoder` would be expected to be already instantiated according to this documentation. What am I missing in my configuration?

**Update**

After Steve Riesenberg's help, I have the following code compiling now. You can see in my code snippet what I used to have working (i.e., before we had the multi-tenant requirement) is now commented out:

`//.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter);`

```
String[] issuers = new String[] {"https://www.example.com/auth/realms/example"};
JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver jwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver =
    new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(issuers);
...
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(
            oauth2ResourceServerConfigurer ->
                oauth2ResourceServerConfigurer
                    .authenticationManagerResolver(jwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver)
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationExceptionHandler));
    // .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
```

However, without the ability now to supply my own token converter since I had to remove `.jwt()`, I'm still unclear on what the default converter provides me.

Also, I'm not clear why I need to use the third constructor of `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` and provide my own `AuthenticationManagerResolver<String>`? If my code above is compiling, why do I need to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The `JwtDecoder` is required if you've configured the resource server with a `JwtAuthenticationProvider` (because it requires a specific `JwtDecoder`). This would happen if you do for example:

```java
http
    ...
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)
        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
    )
```

Since the `authenticationManagerResolver` is an alternative that branches at the `AuthenticationManager` level, you don't want to use a `JwtAuthenticationProvider`. It will be used internally by the `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver`.

Remove `.jwt()` in that case to prevent the configurer from wiring one up.

**Update**

The section in the docs on [Dynamic Tenants](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#dynamic-tenants) gives some more info on various customization options.

In your case, without the use of `.jwt()` you cannot as easily wire in a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` that can customize the returned granted authorities.

The `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` is internally using a `TrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver`. This is what performs the multi-tenancy capability, by extracting an `issuer` claim from the JWT, and creating a `JwtDecoder` + `new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder)` based on the matched `issuer`.

In order to customize the `JwtAuthenticationProvider`, you will have to re-implement this class so you can inject your `JwtAuthenticationConverter` into each created instance. You will implement `AuthenticationManagerResolver<String>` to do this. Call it `CustomTrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver` (see [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4b0e74aac4d56e0cfd641432e58854464993b8ce/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver.java#L191)).

You just need to provide that to the `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver`, like this:

```java
String[] issuers = new String[] {"https://www.example.com/auth/realms/example"};
AuthenticationManagerResolver<String> authenticationManagerResolver =
    new CustomTrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver(issuers);
JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver jwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver =
    new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver);
...
```

Comment: Currently, my configuration contains ```.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)```. This converter is a bean that implements ```Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>```. It's job is to extract the principal and GrantedAuthorities from the Jwt and ```return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, principalName)```. If I remove ```.jwt()``` as you suggest, then where can I wire in this bean in my configuration? Currently, the ```jwtAuthenticationConverter``` method can only be invoked directly after the ```.jwt()``` method.

Comment: To give you an idea of why I have this converter configured, I then use the ```JwtAuthenticationToken``` to do things like authorize a REST controller endpoint invocation using custom ```@PreAuthorize``` code I've developed that evaluates the GrantedAuthorities contained in the ```JwtAuthenticationToken```.

Comment: So, the part that I'm missing is, with the approach of using the ```JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver```, how can I get access to an instance of ```JwtAuthenticationToken```, and where and how is that instance configured? I hope my explanation of what I currently do and why is clear.

Comment: I'd have to check to make sure it works with 5.3 (if that's the version you're using, from your docs link) but you can try adding `@Bean public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() { ... }`.

Comment: We are using Spring Cloud 2020.0.3 and Spring Boot 2.5.6. So, transitively through those pom imports we are using Spring Security 5.5.3.

Comment: Ok. You should be getting a different error in that case saying you can't use both `.jwt()` and the `.authenticationManagerResolver()`. I just checked and it looks like you cannot inject a custom `JwtAuthenticationConverter` into the `.authenticationManagerResolver()`. It always uses the default. You'll have to use the third constructor of `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` and provide your own `AuthenticationManagerResolver<String>` instead of `TrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver` which is package-private.

Comment: I have updated my original post with an update. Please see my comments there. I am still unsure of how at runtime I can access a token that contains all the claims available in the JWT. Today, I control this via invoking the ```.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)``` method, which ends up creating a ```JwtAuthenticationToken```.

Comment: While that feels like a different question, it's fairly related. I updated the answer.

Comment: This is very helpful. In your opinion, is the ability to wire in custom ```JwtAuthenticationConverter``` a worthwhile modification the Spring Security team could build in for applications that use the multi-tenancy capabilities provided by Spring Security?

Comment: Are you saying I have to entirely re-implement the ```JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver ``` class?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238622/discussion-between-steve-riesenberg-and-keith-bennett).